# Postgres apt upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04 hangs every time

Tags: postgresql

On Ubuntu 18.04: any time apt lists postgres as available for upgrade, it hangs forever like this:

```
Setting up postgresql-server-dev-12 (12.9-1.pgdg18.04+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-12 (12.9-1.pgdg18.04+1) ...
(47 years later)
```

Trying to cancel it usually doesn't work and I have to manually kill the entire upgrade process. It prompts me to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but that has the same problem.
This happens on all versions (12, 13, and 14).

I've tried it with postgres both already started and stopped to no avail.

Comment: Is there anything useful in `/var/log/syslog` or in any of the `apt` logs? Was PostgreSQL originally installed via the default repositories or did it come from a different source? 

Comment: not really, syslog just has:
`Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service. Started Daily apt download activities.`
and dpkg.log just has:
`2021-12-04 11:49:25 configure postgresql-12:amd64 12.9-1.pgdg18.04+1 <none>
    2021-12-04 11:49:25 status half-configured postgresql-12:amd64 12.9-1.pgdg18.04+1 `